# Python: When looping and adding a string to another got --> TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, string, capitalization, capitalize

I know it is a recurrent topic in *StackOverflow*, however I'm struggling a lot to find a solution to this case in other posts.

I just want to capitalize the first letter of a sring (descrbing sth) for every srting in `df.Description`

Could anyone tell why I can't loop over `df.Description` in this case?

```
for idx in df.Description.index:
    df.Description.iloc[idx] = df.Description.iloc[idx][0].capitalize() \
                               + df.Description.iloc[idx][1:]


df.head()
Out[22]: 
  Type of Technology  ... Sector
0            CF4_TCE  ...  Dummy
1            CH4_TCE  ...  Dummy
2           CH4g_TCE  ...  Dummy
3           CH4n_TCE  ...  Dummy
4           CH4o_TCE  ...  Dummy
[5 rows x 7 columns]

df.Description
Out[24]: 
0        Tetrafluoromethane (CF4) Total Carbon Emissions
1              Methane total carbon equivalent emissions
2      CH4 emissions from animals directly in Total C...
3      CH4 emissions from anaerobic waste decompostio...
4      Dummy technology converting CH4 emissions from...
                             ...                        
362    conservation cost curve step for transport demand
363    conservation cost curve step for transport demand
364    conservation cost curve step for transport demand
365    conservation cost curve step for transport demand
366    joint diffusion constraint for transport conse...
Name: Description, Length: 367, dtype: object
```

Thanks a lot in advance

The following suggestion from @Marcel M solved this issue:

```
df.Description = df.Description.str[0].str.upper() + df.Description.str[1:]
```

Comment: Can you post `df.head()`?

Comment: @James

`df.head()
Out[22]: 
  Type of Technology  ... Sector
0            CF4_TCE  ...  Dummy
1            CH4_TCE  ...  Dummy
2           CH4g_TCE  ...  Dummy
3           CH4n_TCE  ...  Dummy
4           CH4o_TCE  ...  Dummy
[5 rows x 7 columns]`

Comment: Please edit the original post, don't post as a comment.

Comment: Try `df.Description = df.Description.str[0].str.upper() + df.Description.str[1:]`

Comment: @MarcelM I don't know how to vote as 'useful comment' your answer as a way to thank you... I see someone else already did it

Comment: @franpalma I wrote a full answer now which you should be able to upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
df.Description = df.Description.str[0].str.upper() + df.Description.str[1:]
```

As [described in the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#working-with-text-data), you can use the `.str` attribute of a column to get access to various string processing methods that emulate standard Python string manipulation, but work on the entire column. `df.Description.str[0]` returns a new Series object of the first character of each string. Then `.str.upper()` is used to uppercase that character.

A simpler alternative colud be to use [`capitalize()` or possibly `title()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.capitalize.html) like this:

```
df.Description = df.Description.str.capitalize()
```

or

```
df.Description = df.Description.str.title()
```

However, in your case, this is probably undesirable because these would incorrectly change "CH4" to "ch4" or "Ch4", respectively.